# Export .doc (word) to .cdr (coreldraw)

Tags: microsoft-word, export, coreldraw, documents

I have a word (.docx) file containing Arabic (right to left of course) text. Is there any way to export it to CorelDRAW (`.cdr`) format while retaining the ability to edit text?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to be using some sort of DTP app instead?

Comment: Actually, the doc file is really old, that I need to convert to cdr and edit, I'm not starting from scratch here.

Comment: How big is the document? If it's only a page or so then it might be worth just doing a cut a paste job and re-laying it out in Corel Draw.

Comment: Couple hundred pages :P

Comment: Even I am looking for such an option!

Answer (score 1):

Just Print to PDF (PDF re Direct v2), then import the PDF into CorelDraw. I guess layout will still be preserve in Coreldraw with this option.